# I need to rewrite all my urls. Should i put R=301 in RewriteRule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Currently my URLS are horrible.
They are like:

```
http://www.racebooking.net/single_news.php?id=211
```

And i want them to look better and to be more SEO Friendly, like

```
http://www.racebooking.net/news/video-122.html
```

I am going to do it through Apache .htaccess. Surfing the web i found many different opinions about SEO. Some people say it's not good to use RewriteRule because it creates duplicated content and kills pagerank, but you have to send a 301 message.

Here comes the question: it's better to use

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution
```

or

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [R=301,L]
```

to make my URLS look better without worsening my SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+single_news\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1.html? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^news/([^/.]+)/?$ /single_news.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I admit i'm not rlly used with regexp and htaccess...and i'm finding really hard to understand this logic. As i noticed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306229/301-redirect-in-stackoverflow-how-does-it-works (and i would love to hear your opinion) the redirecting can be done via PHP, which is easier to me. Here come the question: for pagerank and SEO is it the same if i bring the logic of redirecting inside PHP files, minimizing the .htaccess complexity? In this specific case can i manage to do it via PHP? How?

Comment: I would recommend keeping these redirection rules outside your PHP code. This syntax may appear quirky initially but much easier to manage. Consider case of another pretty URL requirement and that will require another few lines in PHP code. Rewrite logic may change depending upon different install also and in that case also PHP code may require another change :)